# Why Silverlight binding doesnt work?

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding

I have 2 listboxes populated by data like so:

```
GoogleNewsResults.Add(
          new News() 
          { 
             Content = "News Content", Title = "News Title" 
          });
NotifyPropertyChanged("GoogleNewsResults");
GoogleBlogsResults.Add(
          new Blog() 
          { 
             Content = "Blog Content", Title = "Blog Title" 
          });
NotifyPropertyChanged("GoogleBlogsResults");
```

But it doesnt update Blog Results listbox. Do you have any idea why?
The XAML has this type of binding:

```
<sllb:ListBox x:Name="GoogleBlogsList" ItemsSource="{Binding GoogleBlogsResults, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this [Tutorial](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/binding/silverlight-data-binding#Exercise2) may help you

i think you need to binding source in XAML

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomerContainerObject}}"
```

or

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

```
  var employees = new List<Employee>() 
{
new Employee { Name = "Scott" },
new Employee { Name = "Poonam"},
new Employee { Name = "Paul" }
};
this.DataContext = employees;
```

wish that helps.

Answer (score 2):

As your GoogleBlogsResults property is a

```
    List<Blog>
```

adding items to it will not trigger the binding engine to fire as the object reference has not changed when you call

```
    NotifyPropertyChanged("GoogleBlogsResults");
```

You can solve this by following the solution described by T.Ho by using

```
    ObservableCollection<Blog>
```

which triggers the binding engine automatically when items within the collection are modified or alternatively by generating a new

```
    List<Blog>
```

object (which merges the new and old items) and setting the GoogleBlogsResults property to the new list.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of implement INotifyProperityChanged interface yourself, you might want to use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead for your list items. ObservableCollection is a collection class with INotifyProperityChanged implemented, so you don't have to manually call "NotifyPropertyChanged" for the binding to update.

Make sure you have  the right DataContext. If you're not using MVVM design pattern, you might want to look into that.